# I need a form that will apply a class to a div if a checkbox in form is checked then have submit button print the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, printing, addclass

The set up is when the user arrives on the page, it will have their information on the page they put in a previous form to review. Also on the page will be a form with 3 options listed with a checkbox by each option, and a button at the bottom of the form that says "Print."

The information at the top of the page that the user is reviewing is also applied to 3 letters that are wrapped in divs with display hidden. Each checkbox represents one of the hidden letters, let's say letter1, letter2 and letter3.

So, I need a form that will have a checkbox for each of the 3 letters, a submit button that prints the entire page upon clicking, and for the form to apply a class to each of the selected letter's div when the print button is clicked, so the print.css will only print the divs that have this class applied to it. I'd preferably like all this done using javascript or jquery, but really any simple method is welcome.

Thank you to all that help!

```
<form action="" id="letterPrint">

<input type="checkbox" name="letter1" value="letter1" /> Letter 1

<input type="checkbox" name="letter2" value="letter2" /> Letter 2

<input type="checkbox" name="letter3" value="letter3" /> Letter 3

<input type="submit" value="print" />

</form>
```

This is my form thus far.

Comment: You're asking a lot of different things in this question and you haven't shown any evidence that you've attempted anything yourself.

Comment: You're aware that there is no attribute `label`? There's an **element** `label` though: `<label for="letter1">Letter 1</label>` where the `for` attribute has to be equal to the `id` attribute of the relevant `input`.

Comment: I apologize. The thing I can't figure out how to do is apply a class to a div when a checkbox is checked and form is submitted. I have a page built out and a form made with the options available. I haven't really tried to do this specific thing yet because I've been searching and have been unsuccessful in finding a solution that fits my needs. I added my form to the question. The last thing I need to do is add that functionality, but being a novice in javascript I can't really find what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Is this kind of what you're looking for?](http://jsfiddle.net/sdleihssirhc/6wWCL/1/)

Comment: Interesting; it works when I click the labels but not when I click the checkboxes (Firefox 3.6.12 on Win, Firefox 3.6.11 on Linux)

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need! Does it apply a class to all letters chosen?

Comment: I have to test this out but this looks like what I've been looking for. Thank you!

Comment: I can't quite get this to work. I linked to the current mootools framework. I also have php on the page and am testing locally. I pretty much copied and pasted over exactly what you have there, but when I hit print it just reloads the same page and no print options come up like with your example. Am I missing a step?

Comment: @Zach It actually doesn't need Mootools. JSFiddle just loads it by default. The reason your page is reloading (this is just a guess; maybe you could link to a live example?) is because, the "Print" button is actually a form, and that form isn't getting the "don't submit" message that JavaScript is trying to tell it. Any more specific than that, and I'd need to see some code.

Comment: I didn't have mootools on there at first, I just linked to it to see if it would work. I put up the file I'm working on at http://www.zachwoomer.com/test.php I just put the file so you could check out the code, if you need anything else let me know. Could the php be interfering with the javascript?

Answer (score 0):

First, adding a print style sheet does not need a class to specific divs. The following code makes it so that when your page prints it will take your print css and apply it to the page before it gets sent off to print.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/screen.css" media="screen" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/print.css" media="print"/>
```

Making it print automatically is more tricky than it would seem. But, you can use this code to bring up the print box

```
if (window.print) {
    window.print();
}
```

Sending a page directly to the printer to be printed is not possible because the print information required to send data to the printer is located on the operating system. JavaScript only interacts with the browser.

Comment: not really, javascript has a function window.print() for printing.

Comment: @Mauricio - but that `window.print()` function only brings up the print dialog, as James said, it doesn't actually start printing (at least with all my browsers on all my systems)

Comment: Even if it's not possible to have a button that will print the page, the main thing I'm trying to figure out is how to apply a class to a div using a form. So the user can choose what letters they want to print, and when the page is printed, everything will have a display none applied to it with the print.css except the divs with the added class.

Comment: @Stephen sorry, I posted that before james edited the answer, where he stated that you can't print in javascript and have to take other language.